# C# - using return in catch clause

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

I saw a similar question here, but there are still some things I don't understand. As far as I know when you use `try-catch` block, if an exception is thrown the catch block will be executed right after and no code after the `catch` clause in the same code block will be executed. So if I get it right if we have:

```
try
{
    // do something
    // throw an exception for some reason
}
catch (Exceptiox ex)
{
    // do something when there is and exception thrown
}
// some code that will never be runned if and exception was thrown above
```

I'm not 100% sure that the `catch` stops further execution outside its scope but this is one of my questions so correct me if I'm wrong.

So what's the point of using `return` in a `catch` block if you don't need to return any value at all? I see this in some methods from inherited code I'm working on. For example:

```
public void DeleteImage(AppConfig imageInfo, string imageName)
{
    string imgPath = imageInfo.ConfigValue.ToString();
    try
    {
        File.Delete(imgPath + "\\" + imageName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex.ToString());
        return;
    }
}
```

Here there is no need to do anything besides logging the error. Why then use `return`. Is it a mistake? Won't the method finish if you don't `return` explicitly? If there was more code after the `catch` clause would it be executed if the `return` wasn't there and the `catch` was used only for logging the error?

Comment: Of course the code after the `try/catch` will execute, that's one of the principal purposes of the `catch`.

Comment: I believe this question was not necessary. Please read first some documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I'm not 100% sure that the catch stops further execution outside it's
>   scope but this is one of my questions so correct me if I'm wrong.

No, that's incorrect. Execution will continue normally after the `catch` block, unless some code inside the block changes the flow (e.g. `throw` or `return`).

Therefore `return` *is* necessary if you don't want execution to continue. Even if there is *currently* no code after the `catch` block, IMHO it's OK to make it more explicit that "handling this type of exception involves not executing any code after this point".

That said, you should be wary of `catch (Exception ex)` -- catching all types of exception should always be questioned and is almost always not quite the right thing to do (although in this case it's for logging, which is an "allowed exception to the rule").

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not 100% sure that the catch stops further execution outside it's scope but this is one of my questions so correct me if I'm wrong.

No, it doesn't. If the catch block doesn't either rethrow or return, execution will continue from the end of the try/catch statement.

In the sample you've given, the `return` statement is pointless. If there *were* code after the catch block, that would be a different matter, as the `return` statement would make the method return immediately.

It's not a *mistake* to have a `return` statement in a `catch` block like that, in that it's perfectly valid code, and will presumably still execute as intended - but it's definitely odd. It could well be that it was cut/paste from a method where the `return` statement *was* important.

(It's also almost always a bad idea to catch `Exception`, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 0):

If there would be no return statement and further any code instead of that, then that code would have got executed. And you are allowed to return any thing from catch block. There is no restrictions for it.